# Answers/questions filter names are not able to be localized

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, localization, filtering

The *[Low quality posts](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts)* and the *[First posts](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts)* queues have filter option, and that option is not localized (tested for ruSO, ptSO, esSO, jaSO), i.e. not found in Transifex:

> [image: question]

> [image: answers]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These will be localized (or at least in Transifex, if the "Questions" and "Answers" aren't already in there) starting with the next build.