# Some new strings on the /review section are not on Transifex

Tags: bug, status-completed, international-sites

Recently we found a couple of strings that are not on transifex:

[image]

Can you check out if you are working on this view, and take care of add them to transifex?

Affecteds key are:

06dd2a8bb2c59d9ab1e69e6f2197b766
585d0000a92fcdd48420af2a3d1653cf

Comment: Heh ... [Aaron assured me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322008/link-to-meta-queues-broken-on-wide-screens/322012#comment1053753_322012) that there is no problem.

Comment: BTW You forgot about the "Meta reviews". Check the image on [ruSO.meta duplicate](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8499/176217).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry about that. Looks like the string export to Transifex failed on our last production build. We kicked off another export, and the strings should be there now.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: Could you please also fix the [small and related, but long standing issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300258/339911) with translations?

Comment: Adam, could you link me to any meta.se  update post or announcement post about changes to the review queue main page (I primarily use math.se).  I understand user identicons have decreased in size, but I've also noticed some queues with fewer than six (most recent) user identicons.  I just want to understand the new scheme.

Comment: See [Counter's text is truncated in queue on localized sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319317/counters-text-is-truncated-in-queue-on-localized-sites/322036#322036) @amWhy - the change is concerned with making the page responsive, allowing it to scale smoothly to different screen sizes. Should not effect which users are visible. If you're using an ad blocker  / privacy extension, check its settings: users with Facebook, Google, Gravatar avatars may not appear if you're blocking their images.